# SyntaxError while exploding the json dataframe column

Tags: pandas

I am trying splitting a json column into multiple column. I am  using the below query and it worked well before but for some reason I am getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
 df["column_config"] = df["column_config"].apply(lambda x: dict(eval(x)))
 final = df('column_config').reset_index(drop=True)
```

here is the sample data frame

```
 company_id   column_config
 1            [{"username":"Rob","type":"Admin","Id":"f3234ds","prefixType":""},{"username":"Lew","type":"Finance","Id":"d32423d","prefix":"Mr"}]

 2           [{"username":"Bob","type":"Admin","Id":"t43234s","prefixType":""}]
```

expected output

```
 company_id   username    type      Id      prefix
  1             Rob       Admin    f3234ds
  1             Lew       Finance  d32423d     Mr
  2             Bob       Admin    t43234s
```

Not sure why I am getting this error. Is there any we can achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "company_id": [1, 2],
        "column_config": [
            '[{"username":"Rob","type":"Admin","Id":"f3234ds","prefixType":""},{"username":"Lew","type":"Finance","Id":"d32423d","prefix":"Mr"}]',
            '[{"username":"Bob","type":"Admin","Id":"t43234s","prefixType":""}]',
        ],
    }
)
```

Here is how to do it with Pandas [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
df["column_config"] = df["column_config"].apply(eval)

df = df.explode("column_config").reset_index(drop=True)

df = (
    pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df["column_config"])], axis=1)
    .drop(columns="column_config")
    .fillna("")
)
```

Then:

```py
   company_id username     type       Id prefixType prefix
0           1      Rob    Admin  f3234ds
1           1      Lew  Finance  d32423d                Mr
2           2      Bob    Admin  t43234s
```

Answer (score 0):

if your *column_config* is json string, then it would be more safe to use `literal_eval` from `ast` module insted of `eval` function, or you can use `json.loads`:

```
from json import loads

pd.concat(df.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(loads(x.column_config)).
                   assign(company_id=x.company_id),axis=1).values,
          ignore_index=True)
>>>
'''
  username     type       Id prefixType prefix  company_id
0      Rob    Admin  f3234ds               NaN           1
1      Lew  Finance  d32423d        NaN     Mr           1
2      Bob    Admin  t43234s               NaN           2
```